# How to solve this thing related to Package Manager?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I installed ProBuilder for my last project, today I started my new project but ProBuilder is not showing in Tools(Tools option is also not visible). Do I have to install it from Package Manager again?
Q

Answer (score 1):

Packages are project specific. So yes, you will need to install the package for this project.

Comment: Thank you for helping but i can't understand why someone downvoted my question. Is there any thing wrong in my question?

Comment: Other than demonstrating you didnt check, which implies lack of effort, something that doesnt sit well in this community.  Also, tbh its not really a SO question. Its a using unity question.. so I guess theres a few reasons.